# Search Core Results Webpart and Data View Webpart

Tags: 2007, data-view-web-part, search

1. We know that Search core results(SCR-WP) webpart can return a max of 50 results per page. Is there any way to increase this number to 2000 or so ?
2. The reason for point no. 1 is that, I've modified the XSL in the SCR-WP to return me the results like a Data view webpart with the Filter Toolbar (which includes sort and groups). Now the filter dropdowns contains values only of the CURRENT PAGE. Is there any way to make the filter dropdown contain values of THE ENTIRE RESULT SET ? If no, then is there a solution for point no. 1 ?
3. Is there a way in which we can store automatically the "keywords" we search(in a search page,in sharepoint) into a List ? Also is there a way to modify the Search Box in the sharepoint search page to feature Autocomplete (picking data from the list) ?

I'm working on sharepoint 2007

Thanks a million for the help.